# How to conditionally render component in <Field> of redux-form

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, field, redux-form

In my code, was trying to render a `<DatePicker>` in `<Field>` component of Redux Form, via a function called `renderDatePicker()`. This function is linked to `handleClick()` function where the state variable `isOpen` is set to `true`.

So ideally, `onClick` should render the `<DatePicker>` as it is set to visible. But code doesn't update anything. Where am I doing wrong here?

Note: Rendering `<DatePicker>` alone directly without the help of `<Field component=...>`, works fine.

For debugging, complete code is in CodeSandbox,

[image: Edit Redux Form - Simple Example]

*SimpleForm.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { reduxForm } from "redux-form";
import { Field } from "redux-form";
import DatePicker from "react-mobile-datepicker";

class SimpleForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: new Date(),
      isOpen: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  renderDatePicker = () => (
    <DatePicker
      value={this.state.time}
      isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
      onSelect={this.handleSelect}
      onCancel={this.handleCancel}
    />
  );

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true }, function() {
      console.log(this.state.isOpen);
    });
  }

  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };

  handleSelect = time => {
    this.setState({ time, isOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="select-btn" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          select time
        </button>
        <Field
          name="date"
          type="date"
          component={this.renderDatePicker}
          label={"date"}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: "simple" // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior lies in the implementation of react-form's `Field` component. It does a shallow compare of all its properties to decide whether it should rerender. You can change your component's `state` as much as you like, the reference to `this.renderDatePicker` won't change.

`Field` passes properties including an `onChange` handler and the current `value` into the field's `component` stateless function call to notify of changes, but this doesn't really apply here because your toggle button is outside of the field.

So one option that comes to my mind is to move your button into the rendered field and then call `onChange(!value)`.

The easier yet dirtier option would be to use an arrow function in your `component` property: `component={() => this.renderDatePicker()}` - this instance changes with every re-render of your `SimpleForm` (i.e. if the `state` changes), so it comes with a cost, but depending on the complexity of your application the cost is negligible. To mitigate the impact, you could implement `shouldComponentUpdate` (just like redux-form's `Field` does) to decide whether it should rerender or not, based on the current and next `isOpen` state.

Check this bit in redux-form for more details: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/createField.js#L44

Comment: Helpful! I've also tried `this.forceupdate()` in callback of `setState` > `handleClick()`. But that has no effect.

Comment: @AbhinavKinagi yeah, no effect because it only impacts your `SimpleForm` component but not necessarily the `Field` and its `component`, for the reasons given above.